# Should I CleanTestdevice Infromation from My code

Tags: android, admob

> With our advertising programs, we strive to create an online ecosystem that benefits publishers, advertisers and users. For this reason, we sometimes have to take action against accounts that demonstrate behavior toward users or advertisers that may negatively impact how the ecosystem is perceived. In your case, we have detected invalid activity in your AdSense account and it has been disabled.

well yesterday google closed my admob account. and they send me this mail. 
To preventint closing Admob account, Should I add this code:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
.addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // My Galaxy Nexus test phone
.build();
```

Also I am not clicking my admob. But I want to prevent Admob close. How should make strong (not closing)Admob?

Answer (score 0):

Since your account was closed for "invalid activity", the code you present may be one possible solution, but it comes down to the more exact (not disclosed by AdMob in this case) reasoning behind it. The code you present will only remove invalid activity from your own personal device, if you have previously clicked or viewed ads on it yourself.

I encourage reading ["How Google prevents invalid activity"](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3342135?hl=en) and ["AdSense program policies"](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182). Key points to evaluate against how you've acted with your account are:

> Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate impressions and/or clicks artificially, including manual methods. Clicks on Google ads must result from genuine user interest. Any method that artificially generates clicks or impressions on your Google ads is strictly prohibited. These prohibited methods include, but are not limited to, repeated manual clicks or impressions, automated click and impression generating tools and the use of robots or deceptive software. Please note that clicking your own ads for any reason is prohibited.
>
> Publishers may not ask others to click their ads or use deceptive implementation methods to obtain clicks. This includes, but is not limited to, offering compensation to users for viewing ads or performing searches, promising to raise money for third parties for such behavior or placing images next to individual ads.

In short, don't view, click or promote ads yourself. Only let your real users view and click ads out of their own free will.